# .NET Inject transient into singleton

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

Suppose I have a singleton service that needs to receive other objects via constructor injection.

What should be the lifetime of these dependencies, they should also be added as singletons?

Are any drawbacks for injecting transient services into singleton objects? I am thinking that even they are transient they will be in memory until the app shuts down because they are injected into a singleton object.

How do we handle such cases?

Comment: if you set the reference to null(in singleton object), i think it can be garbage collected.

Comment: Imho a service should be more or less lifetime-agnostic, meaning it doesn't know whether it is a singleton or transient - it only knows its dependencies. And the instantiator (i. e. DI container) has to take this into account. So if your service needs a "transient" dependency (i. e. a dependency that gets recreated on every call), you better inject a factory delegate and register this delegate in the DI container.

Answer (score 0):

This doc has some guidance on the matter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes

In general I think the standard guidance is to ensure dependencies are registered with longer lifetimes than dependents. If you break this model, you run the risk of causing bad state between requests.